# Python web service

Tags: python, web-services, twisted

I'm doing server/client application similar to Ubuntu Landscape (http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape) for my school project.
The client part of application will send different informations (disk usage, packages etc.) to server. I know how to get informations and hot I'll handle them on the server side.
But I don't know how what is the best way to exchange informations. Would SOAP be ok or is there any better way for doing this? Messages can be large (for example a list of installed packages) or very small. I was looking at Twisted but don't know where to start. I have experience with SOAP in PHP, Java and C#.

And recommnedation is welcome, thanks

Comment: Simple XMLRPC or JSON-RPC is not good enough?

Comment: It might be, I'm lookig for suggestions...

Comment: There are two questions here: _which protocol?_ and _which networking engine?_, you might be better off asking them separately. If you ask a separate Twisted question try to identify what exactly it is you're having trouble understanding - for example which section of the documentation isn't clear?

Comment: @Peter Le Bek: you are right, I'll ask it in a separate thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into XMLRPC or JSON-RPC which is likely supported in some why by all language through modules or packages.

SOAP is a complete bloat and widely considered as a failed hype.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [smisk](http://python-smisk.org/). Both frameworks are REST based, powerful, lightweight and pythonic. Flask is probably more mature and maintained. If you go down the SOAP road, you'll regret it sooner or later.

Comment: REST is not a RPC mechanism - and REST makes only sense when you have something like resources....being more specific: RPC is also about serialization and deserialization of parameters...

Comment: I don't see where the original question is requesting an RPC mechanism. What makes you think 'resources' is not sufficient. Also, the definition of resources is highly subjective.