# Python web service with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

This is connected with my previous question [Python web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642999/python-web-service).

I'll use Tornado to exchange information between server and clients. There will be one server and N clients. Clients will send information (disk usage, processes etc.) periodically (every 2 minutes or so). The data on client side will be represented by custom classes/lists. It would be nice to have the same data on the other side (server).

I have experience with SOAP and it would probably be ok for this (with enough bit timeouts on the server), but would rather use something more light and pythonic. The communication will be more or less only client -> server.

Both server and client side are writen in Python.

What should I look for in Twisted documentation for doing this kind of stuff?

**edit:** I'm not asking on how to serialize data (JSON or pickle or XML etc.). I would like to know what are the options of Twisted to transport data.

With SOAP I would have methods like this:

```
- sendDiskUsage(DiskUsage class instance)
- sendProcesses(ProcessList class instance)
- etc..
```

I would like to know what are the options with Twisted. One of them is XML-RPC which would be ok, but it's not my favourite...

**edit2:** the communication will be "two way" - client's will read tasks from server...

Comment: Just a note about formatting your question: use SO' markdown, do not include HTML tags directly.

Comment: +1 for "more pythonic than soap".

Comment: I'm confused - why is Tornado involved here?  Are you using Cyclone? https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone/

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [AMP](http://amp-protocol.net/). It's a very simple key-value pair based protocol, ideal for what you're doing. Perspective broker is another alternative.. but it's slightly complicated, and usually unnecessary.

AMP runs directly over TCP (why bother with HTTP?), the serialization format is both minimal and logical. This makes it 'light' and 'pythonic' in the sense you probably mean, but those terms could be interpreted in a few different ways.

Take a look at the AMP examples on [Twisted code examples](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/), they're pretty self-explanatory. AMP connections are bi-directional, so try modifying the example so that the server asks the client for its current disk usage. The [`twisted.protocols.amp`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html) API docs will be useful here.

When you're ready to build a real application read [Twisted from Scratch, or The Evolution of Finger](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html).

AMP has been implemented in most of the popular languages, but if you're looking for something more 'mainstream', [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is Google's thing. IMO it's overcomplicated and lacks some important features like error feedback.

Comment: +1, good summary of the options; but perspective broker is really a good analog for SOAP, It goes a long way to fix many of the weaknesses of pickle for remote applications, and its definitely worth a close look when both peers are python.

Comment: Ouch!  "Good analog for SOAP"!  It burnsssss.  Ahem.  But seriously.  AMP is probably a good idea as a first choice.  If it turns out to be inconvenient, then switching to PB is fairly straightforward.  The opposite is not so easily done, since PB gives you remote references, cacheables, and all sorts of other things, all while making the actual API less explicit than AMP does.  It's totally true that AMP is less featureful than PB, but sometimes that's a feature itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try twisted's “perspective broker“. It has a few nice features, such as symmetry (there is no real difference betweenclient and server, once a connection is established). It takes care of serialization itself. It might not be the best choice, if you only want a simple one-way status update push.

Answer (score 1):

For data serializing, if you are using pickle to serialize custom class instances, do make sure that both the server and the client have the same class definition in the global namespace.

For twisted reference, you may take a look at its [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html), especially the 'Writing a TCP server' and 'Writing a TCP client' part.

Answer (score 0):

If both server and client are written in Python the simplest way is just to do a HTTP POST request from the cliente to the server having data serialized to pickled Python objects. Pickles will carry all the orignal object structure.

If the client is non-pythonic process then JSON is the way to go - you just serialize objects to JSON. The difference between pickles and JSON is that JSON cannot transport classes, just data as nested lists and dicts.

HTTP POSTs with JSON payload - this is what I would do.

Do not bother with SOAP. WSDL etc. adds just extra complexity to the process, is very un-pythonic and Python SOAP libraries are not that robust.

Twisted documentation does not cover this kind of stuff, because this is a generic Python problem, not specific to Twisted.

Comment: Hm, I would rather see how to use Twisted's reactor, perscpective broker etc. make this. I agree that pickle/JSON is a better way to send data than SOAP (because there is no really good server side lib for SOAP in Python). I'll add to my question that both client and server side are Python.

Comment: HTTP POSTs are considerably harder than either AMP or PB method calls.